# How to calculate Percentages of NDVI Classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi

I Have calculated the NDVI Using Landsat. I Classify it by threshold value of 0.25
 I Then made 5 classes. Now i want to calculate the percentages of each class individually. please reckon me process.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use reclassify tool in the spatial analyst toolbox with your layer as input. This will create a new file with classes based on your layer symbology. Open the attribute table of this file (by right clicking) and you will have the number of pixels per class.
use reclassify tool in the spatial analyst toolbox with your layer as input. This will create a new file with classes based on your layer symbology. Open the attribute table of this file (by right clicking) and you will have the number of pixels per class.

After the pixel count,

1. create a new field as float.
2. right click on the field and Open the field calculator
3. multiply the field by (Pixel/TotalPixelCount)*100  (always remember to validate the total area by the result of the pixel count.)

Alternatively, you can export the table to .dbf or .txt format and compute the percentages in Excel